# why linked list is faster

Tags: java, linked-list

I know  `linkedlist` is faster in insertion and deletion in java because they use linked list datastructure which is group of nodes. I tried to understand why it is faster  in insertion and deletion.But I did not understand. What I have undersstood is Each node is composed of data and a reference to the next node. Now, How it is efficient because of this? can I anyone explain me in simple way? Sorry I am not a computer science student.
Just have completed Bachelor commerce.. :)

Comment: faster than what, exactly? if you're comparing to arrays, the main reason is because an array has a fixed size, and so would need to be 'recreated' on insert/delete

Comment: @Eran you pointed to an also duplicate  answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26737018/3584765 instead of the original: http://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/3584765

Comment: @Eypros I pointed to the same question asked by the same user.

Comment: @Eran I still don't get why you should point to a question that is also duplicate and not the original one even if it's of the same person. It's like chain answer instead of the direct one. Anyway, I made my point clear won't comment any more

Answer (score 0):

In case of linked list, there is no boundation that it should be saved in contiguous memory, so where ever there is space in memory, JVM puts object there and points that object from last element of the list.

But in case of say, `ArrayList`, if JVM does not find contiguous memory space, JVM finds new memory area that can accommodate complete `ArrayList` and then copies complete list to that space, hence adds overhead.